# One PagerAdapter for multiple fragments

Tags: android

I have a basic PagerAdapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Main tab1 = new Main();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            Secondary tab2 = new Secondary();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            Third tab3 = new Third();
            return tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

It works perfectly for one tablayout and 3 fragments which are displayed in the viewpager. I have multiple of the same fragment design (same tabs) across a few fragments. Is it possible to use this one PagerAdapter with multiple options (fragments), so all it has to change is the classes that are instantiated. 
      `Main tab1 = new Main();` to `SomeOtherClass tab1 = new SomeOtherClass();`. I tried doing this with parameters and variables but no success.

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I have multiple basically the same fragments just with different names,  what I want to do is use one pageradapter to control the the fragments in the viewpager. The fragments being displayed depend on a previously selected option (button). They can be changed. For example one time the fragments being displayed are A, B and C next time, when the other option is selected the fragments being displayed are D, E and F.And this is all controlled using one pager adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `public Fragment getItem(int position);` method, you should return the fragment in the `mFragmentList`for the given position. Something like this:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}
```

By this way you can use this adapter for any Fragment.

Also, the method getCount() should be as follow:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList!=null ? mFragmentList.size() : 0;
}
```

In order to avoid hardcoded values.

Comment: Got it working. Haven't worked on this project for a while and I'm a new comer to android development so I forgot what this was about

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Good luck!